# Print entire element returned by getElementById

Tags: javascript

If I'm debugging some javascript code and I want to see where I am in the DOM, how can I print the entire element returned by (say) getElementById()?  I know I can print a field:

```
attrib = document.getElementById("attrib-2");
alert(attrib.selectedIndex);
```

but if I want to print the whole thing (even children) what can I do?

Comment: do u want to see all markup of element and of all its children??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alert isn't the best option for debugging purposes. Consider using some specifically designed tools like FireBug in Firefox, Developer Tools in WebKit browsers. Then use `console.log` method to see some data you need in highly readable format.

```
attrib = document.getElementById("attrib-2");
console.log(attrib.selectedIndex);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach (k in attrib){
    if (typeof attrib[k]!='function'){
        console.log(attrib[k]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log(attrib)
```

and then check your browser console (F12 in most browsers)

Answer (score 0):

In order to print the entire elemenent you need `console.dir`:

```
var attrib = document.getElementById("attrib-2");
console.dir(attrib);
```

In this way u can inspect the whole object.
Click on the arrows near the object properties, to expand or collapse them.